# How to use Secure Erase and is it on the install CD?

Tags: security, hard-drive, delete

Supposedly there is some built in hard drive magic called "Secure Erase" which is wildly faster and more secure than "dd if=/dev/zero..."

I am most excited about the speed increase.

There seems to be a GUI for it as part of Parted Magic: http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?81321-Secure-Erase-With-bootable-CD-USB-Linux..-Point-and-Click-Method

Is there something like this for Ubuntu?  Better yet, is there a way to actually issue this command "manually" like with smartctl or something?

Comment: While this is a great function, which most modern hard drives support, it is NOT supported on all platforms.  Sometimes it is the controller (or logical addressing), and for some platforms the BIOS does NOT support (or blocks) the 'SecureErase' command (to prevent malicious usage). SEE: http://cmrr.ucsd.edu/people/Hughes/HDDEraseReadMe.txt

Comment: Another good reason to use it is to tell the firmware of modern solid state drives that the data currently existing on the disk is no longer needed.  This can improve performance.

Comment: @LiveWireBT the user did not say he/she was using an SSD

Comment: @Richard No s/he asked how to run ATA Secure Erase and even the solution is the same. The difference in performing ATA Secure Erase on an SSD and an HDD would probably be just a difference in time the process takes to complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Secure Erase is part of ATA standard and it is supported by stock-standard `hdparm` program:

> ```
>   ATA Security Feature Set
>
>    These switches are DANGEROUS to experiment with, and might not work with some kernels.  USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.
>
>    --security-help
>           Display terse usage info for all of the --security-* options.
>
>    --security-freeze
>           Freeze the drive´s security settings.  The drive does not accept any security commands until  next  power-on  reset.
>           Use this function in combination with --security-unlock to protect drive from any attempt to set a new password. Can
>           be used standalone, too.  No other options are permitted on the command line with this one.
>
>    --security-unlock PWD
>           Unlock the drive, using password PWD.  Password is given as an ASCII string and is padded  with  NULs  to  reach  32
>           bytes.   The  applicable  drive password is selected with the --user-master switch (default is "user" password).  No
>           other options are permitted on the command line with this one.
>
>    --security-set-pass PWD
>           Lock the drive, using password PWD (Set Password) (DANGEROUS).  Password is given as an ASCII string and  is  padded
>           with NULs to reach 32 bytes.  Use the special password NULL to set an empty password.  The applicable drive password
>           is selected with the --user-master switch (default is "user" password) and the applicable  security  mode  with  the
>           --security-mode switch.  No other options are permitted on the command line with this one.
>
>    --security-disable PWD
>           Disable drive locking, using password PWD.  Password is given as an ASCII string and is padded with NULs to reach 32
>           bytes.  The applicable drive password is selected with the --user-master switch (default is  "user"  password).   No
>           other options are permitted on the command line with this one.
>
>    --security-erase PWD
>           Erase  (locked) drive, using password PWD (DANGEROUS).  Password is given as an ASCII string and is padded with NULs
>           to reach 32 bytes.  Use the special password NULL to represent an empty password.  The applicable drive password  is
>           selected  with the --user-master switch (default is "user" password).  No other options are permitted on the command
>           line with this one.
>
>    --security-erase-enhanced PWD
>           Enhanced erase (locked) drive, using password PWD (DANGEROUS).  Password is given as an ASCII string and  is  padded
>           with  NULs  to  reach 32 bytes.  The applicable drive password is selected with the --user-master switch (default is
>           "user" password).  No other options are permitted on the command line with this one.
>
>    --user-master USER
>           Specifies which password (user/master) to select.  Defaults to user  password.   Only  useful  in  combination  with
>           --security-unlock, --security-set-pass, --security-disable, --security-erase or --security-erase-enhanced.
>                   u       user password
>                   m       master password
>
>    --security-mode MODE
>           Specifies which security mode (high/maximum) to set.  Defaults to high.  Only useful in combination with --security-
>           set-pass.
>                   h       high security
>                   m       maximum security
>
>           THIS FEATURE IS EXPERIMENTAL AND NOT WELL TESTED. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.
> ```

For obvious reasons, I haven't tested those options, you'll need to see if they work yourself :)

Comment: Might be worth updating your answer to only include the correct advice, for the benefit of future people finding the answer.

Comment: For rotational hard disks, it is usually faster than dd, but not that much.  For SSDs it is usually nearly instantaneous.

Comment: That's a lot of options.  Does anybody know the difference between ``-security-erase`` and ``--security-erase-enhanced``?  Which one is more appropriate for an SSD when the main reason for doing this is to reduce internal fragmentation and not wipe sensitive data?

Comment: There's a [step-by-step tutorial on using hdparm to perform a secure erase](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) on the kernel wiki.